# Is it possible to catch ViewExpriedException in PhaseListener?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, session-timeout, jsf-1.2

For logging purposes, I am interested in detecting when a session timeout occurs in my JSF application.

I have implemented a PhaseListener that checks if users are logged in and have their session already active. My implementation of *afterPhase* method is:

- var **url_accepted** (used in the code) contains a list of public pages that users should have access in order to provide a login form.

  ```
  public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
      FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext();
      HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);

      AuthenticationBean sessionBean = (AuthenticationBean) session.getAttribute("sessionBean");

      String url_req = context.getViewRoot().getViewId();

      //1. Check if user has a session and is logged in:
      if(((sessionBean == null) || (sessionBean != null && !sessionBean.isLoggedIn())) && !url_accepted.contains(url_req)){
          context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context,null,"auth_error");
          return;
      }

  //2. Code continues in order to check if a logged user has permissions to access the requested page(not relevant):        
  }
  ```

When an user has been disconnected due to a session timeout, the PhaseListener cannot retrieve my sessionBean from the **ExternalContext** and assigns **null** to the sessionBean attribute. At this point I cannot distinguish whether the user hasn't been logged-in before or has been disconnected by timeout.

I've read that one can use errorPages in order to detect a **ViewExpiredException** exception and redirect the view to a specific page. But i don't know if it's possible to manage this exception in my source code.

My question is: Can I catch this **ViewExpiredException** inside my PhaseListener implementation in order to handle a session timeout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same scenario in a JSF project. The solution was to use a Filter to catch the session expired. BalusC (JSF Expert) explains this matter and shows a good example:

- [User session filter](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/03/user-session-filter.html)

Additional, don't forget to add [`session.invalidate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29) in your logout method and in your session timeout handler.

Comment: Thank you for the reference & advice. I'll see if I can adapt this BalusC solution in my project.

Comment: If you have any question, just update your post and leave a comment here so I could help you.

Comment: I've been analysing the example proposed by BalusC, but I don't get where he manages the timeout logout. I think he doesn't make any action.

The problem I have in my application already works for session timeout, but I need to catch when it happens so I can log which user has been disconnected because of this.

Let me know if it's already implemented in BalusC code, I'll dig in more detail into the code.